# The sum of all clustering columns is too long (65927 > 65535)

Tags: java, sql, cassandra, nosql

While inserting to Cassandra db this error comes,I am inserting very huge data to the database,Is this error because of memory,i have enough disk space, as i know the row in the data base can hold 2billion records so am i missing column range configuration.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: The sum of all clustering columns is too long (65927 > 65535)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:259)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:175)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
        at FileLogger.persistData(FileLogger.java:91)
        at FileLogger.main(FileLogger.java:59)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: The sum of all clustering columns is too long (65927 > 65535)
```

Comment: The error suggests you have too many "clustering columns" most likely this is a built in limit of the software (as the limit is a round number 2^16-1) rather than the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty clear, your summed column names are greater than what expect cassandra which seems to be (0XFFFF = 65535).

Either you can reduce the names, either you'll have to divide your query.

From : [Link](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/QueryProcessor.java;h=71a57f434ce351b497053955cb04038ee3c15d7c;hb=623ed791)

```
105     public static void validateColumnNames(Iterable<ByteBuffer> columnNames) throws InvalidRequestException
106     {
107         for (ByteBuffer name : columnNames)
108             validateColumnName(name);
109     }
110
111     public static void validateColumnName(ByteBuffer name) throws InvalidRequestException
112     {
113         if (name.remaining() > IColumn.MAX_NAME_LENGTH)
114             throw new InvalidRequestException(String.format("The sum of all clustering columns is too long (%s > %s)",
115                                                             name.remaining(),
116                                                             IColumn.MAX_NAME_LENGTH));
117
118         if (name.remaining() == 0)
119             throw new InvalidRequestException("Invalid empty value for clustering column of COMPACT TABLE");
120     }
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for reply :) , My composite key is ((timestamp_byhour),timestamp,payload).I don't think here column name length matters.But sure it resolved once i removed payload from composite key which is of type text having 2048 character.Still un clear why it failed after 70000 records inserted,It is a single cluster & single node server. If sum of clustering columns are too long then how many columns can be considered in cluster key. Even though i changed text type of payload to blob still same error comes.It will be great if some one can explain what is "sum of all clustering columns"